# How to analytically solve: $\ddot{r} = \frac{k}{m}\frac{1}{r^3}$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, physics, nonlinear-system, classical-mechanics

I'm reading through Susskind-Hrabovsky's [Theoretical Minimum](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0465075681).  I've come across this problem (Ex3): [image: Ex. 3]
Here is what I've done so far:
$$F = - \nabla V$$
choosing polar coordinates:
$$ma = - \frac{\partial V}{\partial r}$$
$$m\ddot{r} = \frac{k}{r^3}$$
Now how can I solve this? Is there an analytical $r(t)$?

Comment: Your equation of motion is wrong.  The acceleration is not just $\ddot{r}$.

Comment: Mathematica gives $$\frac{\sqrt{c_1^2 m t^2+2 c_2 c_1^2 m t+c_2^2
   c_1^2 m+k}}{\sqrt{c_1} \sqrt{m}},$$ for constants $c_1,c_2$ assuming your differential equation is right.

Comment: @RobertIsrael Yeah since a is vector, I should also take into account theta. but I'm now interested in solving that nonlinear ode

Comment: @YiFan I tried inputting it to WolframAlpha but it couldn't solve it. May I ask how did you format the poblem?

Comment: @Zeta.Investigator I used Mathematica, which is different from and more powerful than Wolfram Alpha.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### The vector equation of motion

The equation of motion is
$\newcommand{\fx}{\mathfrak{x}}$
$$
m\ddot\fx=\frac{k\,\fx}{r^4}
$$

### Circular solutions, all constants positive

A circular solution has the form $\fx(t)=(r\cos(u(t)), r\sin(u(t)))$ with some angle function $u(t)$. We get by the chain and product rule
$$
-m\dot u^2\,\fx+m\ddot u\,J\fx=\frac{k\,\fx}{r^4}
$$
where $J$ is a $90^\circ$ rotation matrix. As $\fx$ and $J\fx$ are linearly independent, this implies $\ddot u=0$ and $mr^4\dot u^2=-k$. This last identity can not be satisfied in real numbers, the left side is positive, the right side negative.

---

#### Radial force field, pointing outward

This is conform with the physical intuition that the potential is not a well but a peak at the origin, thus its force field is repelling and can thus not provide the centripetal force that continuously curves the trajectory back towards the origin, which is required for a bounded orbit.

---

### Circular solutions, general constants

If the constants are assumed to allow negative values, then for $k<0$ set $r_c^4=\frac{-k}m$. Then circular orbits of every radius exist, with a constant angular speed of $\dot u=\pm\frac{r_c^2}{r^2}$.

### General solutions

$\newcommand{\fs}{\mathfrak{s}}$
Let $\fs(\alpha)=(\cos(α),\sin(α))$. Then the polar decomposition of the trajectory is $\fx(t)=r(t)\fs(u(t))$. The derivatives are $\dot \fx(t)=\dot r(t)\fs(u(t))+r(t)\fs'(u(t))\dot u(t)$ and 
$$
\ddot \fx(t)=\ddot r(t)\fs(u(t))+2\dot r(t)\fs'(u(t))\dot u(t)-r(t)\fs(u(t))\dot u(t)^2+r(t)\fs'(u(t))\ddot u(t)=-\frac{r_c^4\fs(u(t))}{r(t)^3}
$$
Separating the coefficients of the orthogonal directions $\fs,\fs'$ gives
\begin{align}
0&=\ddot r(t)-r(t)\dot u(t)^2+\frac{r_c^4}{r(t)^3}\\
0&=r(t)\ddot u(t)+2\dot r(t)\dot u(t)&&\implies r(t)^2\dot u(t)=K
\end{align}
which means that the second Kepler law remains in action, the angular momentum is preserved. Now the first equation reduces to
$$
0=\ddot r(t)+\frac{r_c^4-K^2}{r(t)^3}
$$
which in the end leads back to the original differential equation in the question, which is extensively discussed in the other answer. The solution found there is
$$
\sqrt{Cr(t)^2+r_c^4-K^2}=\pm t+D,~~~ C=\dot r_0^2-\frac{r_c^4-K^2}{r_0^2}
$$
So the conclusion is that apart from the case $C=0$ there are no closed orbits, all other solutions spiral inwards or outwards.

Comment: Thanks for your through answer, really appreciated. **1-** Why your first equation is $\frac{k\chi}{r^4}$ when it should be $\frac{k}{r^2}$ ?   **2-** Why are you using both $r$ and $\chi$ as your position vector?

Comment: You can look at the code, it is a fraktur "x", the shape similarity to "r" worked in one way or the other to the selection of the standard letters for unknowns. $\mathfrak x$ stands for the position vector, $r$ for its Euclidean norm. The gradient of $V(\mathfrak x)=\phi(r)$ is $ ∇V=\phi'(r)\frac{\mathfrak x}{r}$.

Comment: **3-** Your definition of "circular" doesn't hold for every phase function $u(t)$, right? Since if we take $u(t) = \sin(t)$ or $u(t) = \log(t)$ the plot doesn't seem to be circular

Comment: Yes, it is the movement on a circle, not necessarily going around the circle. However, the preservation of the angular momentum causes the motion to be always in one direction, never stopping, never turning around.

Comment: Sorry for what it seems to be a trivial question but how did you calculate the vector gradient of V? Can you point me to a literature explaining that? Since I think gradient of V should be r' * phi'(r). I've become confused. Why do we use both $\chi$ for position vector and r (which is half of position vector information in polar coordinates)

Comment: Yes, it is. If you correctly compute the partial derivative vector in $r'=∇r=\frac{(x,y)^\top}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}$

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/99789/discussion-between-zeta-investigator-and-lutzl).

Comment: I actually don't know how to calculate that vector gradient. What is the name of this notion so I could read about it? Partial vector differentiation? Is it part of vector calculus?

Comment: **4** How did you actually get to your second equation which has a rotation matrix in it (and I assume it is $[\cos(\theta), -\sin(\theta);\sin(\theta), \cos(\theta)]$

Comment: Yes, it is vector calculus. As $df_{(x,y)}=\frac{\partial f(x,y)}{\partial x}dx+\frac{\partial f(x,y)}{\partial y}dy$ you get $∇f=(\frac{\partial f}{\partial x},\frac{\partial f}{\partial y})^\top$ so that $\langle ∇f(x,y),v\rangle=df_{(x,y)}(v)$.

Comment: As said, it is a $90^°$ rotation, so that $\pmatrix{\cos(θ)\\\sin(θ)}'=\pmatrix{-\sin(θ)\\\cos(θ)}=\pmatrix{0&-1\\1&0}\pmatrix{\cos(θ)\\\sin(θ)}$.

Comment: **5-** At the top, you assumed r to be constant (hence no $r(t)$) but at the general solution section you assumed a variable radius and variable phase, right?

Comment: **6-** In your derivation for $\ddot \chi(t)$, why suddenly a minus signs appears? (3rd term) $\ddot \chi(t)=\ddot r(t)\chi(u(t))+2\dot r(t)\chi'(u(t))\dot u(t)-r(t)\chi(u(t))\dot u(t)^2+r(t)\chi'(u(t))\ddot u(t)$?

Comment: **7-** Orthogonality of s and s' is a consequence of our coordinate selection (=polar), right?

Comment: **8-** Why suddenly in the middle of solution, you mentioned whether Kepler's second law holds or not? Is Kepler 's second law a "principle" for checking whether a trajectory is possible in real world?

Comment: 5) yes. 6) because the second derivative of sin and cos is minus sin and cos. 7) yes, the tangent on the circle is always orthogonal to the radius vector. 8) Keplers second law about the area of the sector per time increment is the conservation of angular momentum, which results per Noether from the rotational symmetry of the equations. It is the only one of the three Kepler laws that remains true for this potential.

Comment: So checking which of the Kepler's laws hold is an extra and doesn't make your derived trajectory impossible or something?

Comment: Yes, it is just a comment on one communality with other central force-fields.

Comment: Vielen Dank for answering all my follow-up questions. Hope you have a good day :D

Answer (score 2):

$$\frac{d^2r}{dt^2} =\frac{A}{r^3}.$$ Multiply by $2 \frac{dr}{dt}$ on both sides to have $$ 2 \frac{dr}{dt}\frac{d^2r}{dt^2} =2\frac{A}{r^3}.\frac{dr}{dt}.$$ We can rewtite this as
$$ \frac{d}{dt} \left( \frac{dr}{dt}\right)^2=2\frac{A}{r^3}.\frac{dr}{dt}.$$ Now integrate w.r.t. $t$ both sides as
$$ \left( \frac{dr}{dt}\right)^2= \int 2\frac{A}{r^3} dr=-\frac{A}{r^2} +C$$ Here $C$ is the constant of integration. Next, $$\frac{dr}{dt}=\pm \sqrt{C-\frac{A}{r^2}} \implies  \int \frac{dr}{\sqrt{C-\frac{A}{r^2}}}= \pm t+ D.$$ the constanta $C$ and $D$ will be determined y thr initial value of $r$ and $\frac{dr}{dt}$ at the initial time $t=t_0$ This integral is easily doable by letting $r^2=u$.
We get $$\sqrt{Cu-A}=\pm Ct+CD \implies Cu-A=(\pm Ct+CD)^2 \implies r^2=\frac{C}{ (\pm Ct-CD)^2+A}.$$

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I really appreciate it